# Nested ifndef in Makefile

Tags: makefile

In my Makefile I am trying to step through different ways of programatically setting an environment variable in a target. However, each statement inside each `ifndef` appears to be being executed every time. How do I get around this happening?

```
repository:
ifndef REPOSITORY_URI
    @$(eval REPOSITORY_URI := $(shell bash -c "aws --region $(REGION) ecr describe-repositories --repository-names $(APP) | jq -r '.repositories[0].repositoryUri'"))
ifndef REPOSITORY_URI
    @$(eval REPOSITORY_URI := $(shell bash -c "aws --region $(REGION) ecr create-repository --repository-name $(APP) | jq -r '.repositories[0].repositoryUri'"))
ifndef REPOSITORY_URI
    echo "Could not establish link to AWS Repository, please ensure your credentials are set and try again"
endif
endif
endif
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing Make syntax with shell syntax. Are you sure you want to set the variable in the recipe?

Comment: The `ifndef` is expanded when the makefile is first being read, and the `eval` is expanded when the recipe is run.  At read time `REPOSITORY_URI` is undefined and so all of those commands will be expanded in your recipe, and when your recipe is run, those commands get run regardless of what you set `REPOSITORY_URI` to.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `@` signs in front of the `$(eval ...)`s.   They expand to an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to compute a value for the make-variable `REPOSITORY_URI` using
make-functions, but you mistakenly believe that computing a value for a make-variable calls for a make-target and a recipe.

The actual meaning of your recipe for `repository` is quite different from what
you think and explaining what it does mean would be a large digression, since
no target or recipe is needed. To do what you are after here, just write:

```
ifndef REPOSITORY_URI
REPOSITORY_URI := $(shell bash -c "aws --region $(REGION) ecr describe-repositories --repository-names $(APP) | jq -r '.repositories[0].repositoryUri'")
ifndef REPOSITORY_URI
REPOSITORY_URI := $(shell bash -c "aws --region $(REGION) ecr create-repository --repository-name $(APP) | jq -r '.repositories[0].repositoryUri'")
ifndef REPOSITORY_URI
$(error "Could not establish link to AWS Repository, please ensure your credentials are set and try again")
endif
endif
endif
```

at the place in your makefile where you want to assign a value to `REPOSITORY_URI`
(or fail).

This by itself now constitutes a makefile with *no targets*. But presumably you
want to *use* the value of `REPOSITORY_URI` *in* the recipe for one or more targets, e.g.

```
ifndef REPOSITORY_URI
REPOSITORY_URI := $(shell bash -c "aws --region $(REGION) ecr describe-repositories --repository-names $(APP) | jq -r '.repositories[0].repositoryUri'")
ifndef REPOSITORY_URI
REPOSITORY_URI := $(shell bash -c "aws --region $(REGION) ecr create-repository --repository-name $(APP) | jq -r '.repositories[0].repositoryUri'")
ifndef REPOSITORY_URI
$(error "Could not establish link to AWS Repository, please ensure your credentials are set and try again")
endif
endif
endif

.PHONY: all

all:
    echo REPOSITORY_URI=$(REPOSITORY_URI)
```

I recommend [the GNU Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)